# Map (in memory) or Project (SQL) same entity to model using Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm doing a POC to make sure the different concepts we will implement in a rewrite of one of our applications will cover our needs. I'm encountering an issue, where I require a different behavior to do an in memory or SQL query.

Furthermore, I've got these entities (only relevant properties are included):

```cs
public class ProductEntity
{
    public required int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public required ICollection<ProductDescriptionEntity>? Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDescriptionEntity
{
    public required int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public required string Language { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public ProductEntity? Product { get; set; }
}
```

and want to map it to this model:

```cs
public class ProductWithDescription
{
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Note that we want to take the single description corresponding with the user language.

To handle this, I've created this profile:

```cs
public class ProductMappings : Profile
{
    public ProductMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductWithDescription>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Description,
                       exp => exp.MapFrom(src => GetLocalizedDescription(src)));

        CreateProjection<ProductEntity, ProductWithDescription>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Description,
                       exp => exp.MapFrom(src => src.Descriptions!
                                                    .First(description => description.Language == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)
                                                    .Description));
    }

    private static string? GetLocalizedDescription(ProductEntity product) =>
        product.Descriptions
               ?.FirstOrDefault(description => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(description.Language, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
               ?.Description;
}
```

What's defined in `CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductWithDescription>()` works to do an in memory query; what's defined with `CreateProjection<ProductEntity, ProductWithDescription>()` works to do an EF query using `.ProjectTo()`; but I can't get in memory and SQL projects to work both.

It is stated [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/12.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#equivalent-settings-overwrite-each-other) and [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/4056) that Automapper doesn't support different configurations for map and project.

I'm doing this to fall back to a SQL query when our cache hasn't been loaded:

```cs
public async Task<ICollection<TModel>> GetAllAsync<TModel>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
                                                           Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>? orderBy = null)
{
    if (_cache.RunningState != CacheRunningState.Running)
    {
        // fallback to repository if the cache isn't available (yet)
        return await _repository.GetAllAsync<TModel>(predicate, orderBy);
    }

    var filteredEntities = _cache.Entities
                                 .Where(predicate);

    filteredEntities = orderBy == null
        ? filteredEntities
        : orderBy(filteredEntities);

    return _mapper.Map<ICollection<TModel>>(filteredEntities);
}
```

Do you see a solution to my issue?

Comment: Attention: this comment is my own criteria. Stop using automapper. The decision is easy, if the data will be huge use ADO.NET, arrays, profiling, reduce the data with some criteria. If not, EF and own mappings. In any case this question, to my understanding will derive to an opinion based question. Is not bad question, but is opinion based.

Comment: Perhaps you can query here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not using `ProjectTo` with in-memory `IQueryable` as well?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli The only part of this question that is opinion-based is the "would you recommend" query, which can be fully removed from the post without changing what it's asking.

Comment: @IvanStoev it doesn't work either, all descriptions remain `null`.

Comment: @Philippe Then something is wrong with your model/cache. Collections must never be `null` - you must initialize them in the constructor or via initializer. Collection property should not be nullable. e.g. the standard collection navigation property should be something like this `public ICollection<DescriptionEntity> Descriptions { get; set; } = new HashSet<DescriptionEntity>();`

Comment: @IvanStoev I meant the nullable string description of the model `ProductWithDescription` we map to are `null`; not the actual collection. Sorry for the confusion. But this is not true either, I didn't read the test exception thoroughly. It through an exception at runtime when automapper tried to do the mapping because not all products have a description for the set language (as required by the expression set for projecting.

Comment: I see. Then the following expression should work for both queryables `src => src.Descriptions.Where(d =>  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(d.Language, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Select(d => d.Description).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: This works in memory (the expression just misses a parenthesis before the `Select`) but it can't be translate to SQL with `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (I'm not too surprised as the DB is `CI_AS`). If replacing this condition with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == d.Language` it can be translated to SQL but doesn't return any in memory results because `ProductDescriptionEntity.Language` is upper case and `CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` is lower case (even if set like this `new CultureInfo("DE")`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @IvanStoev (see discussion in comments) I've been able to define a map which works for both in memory mappings and SQL projections:

```cs
CreateMap<ProductEntity, ProductWithDescription>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Description,
             exp => exp.MapFrom(src => src.Descriptions
                                          .Where(d => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToUpperInvariant() == d.Language)
                                          .Select(d => d.Description)
                                          .FirstOrDefault()));
```

Not sure I'll keep this concept in place as it might be tedious/impossible to align mappings and projections for more complex scenarios.